# Caching with useQuery and Firestore Query

Tags: react-native, tanstackreact-query, tanstack

In my application I have spots saved in firestore and I fetch them in React Native using Tanstack's useQuery. At start I first fetch all spots at a specific location and display them on a map. The user can then press on a spot and a detail page will open, neatly displaying the data. How should I set the queryKey of the mapSpots, such that in the detail page when using **useSpot(id)** it will use the cached spot from **useMapSpots** and also to be able to later invalidate specific spots instead all of the mapSpots? Do I need to modify fetchAllSpotFromLocation? I cannot use ['spot',id] in useMapSpots since before the queryFn has been executed I do not know the ids.

```js
export function useMapSpots(latitude, longitude, range) {
    return useQuery({
        queryKey: ['mapSpots'],
        queryFn: () => fetchAllSpotFromLocation(latitude, longitude, range),
        enabled: true,
    });
}

export function useSpot(id) {

    return useQuery({
        queryKey: ['spot', id],
        queryFn: () => fetchSpot(id),
        enabled: !!id,
    });
}

const fetchAllSpotFromLocation = async (userLatitude, userLongitude, range) => {

    const center = [userLatitude, userLongitude];
    const bounds = geofire.geohashQueryBounds(center, range * 1000);

    let downloadedSpots = [];

    // Iterate through each bound
    for (const b of bounds) {
        let queries = [];

        // Always query for public spots
        const publicQuery = query(
            collection(firestore, 'spots'),
            orderBy('geoHash'),
            where('public', '==', true),
            startAt(b[0]),
            endAt(b[1])
        );
        queries.push(getDocs(publicQuery));

        // Execute the queries and combine results
        const spotDataArrays = await Promise.all(queries);
        const spots = spotDataArrays.flatMap(spotData =>
            spotData.docs.map(doc => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }))
        );

        downloadedSpots.push(...spots);
    }

    return downloadedSpots;
};
```